# initialising option in <select></select> in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to initialise the value of select dropdown in angular 6, i have following code in html view

```
<select required 
        name="selectedQueryType"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedQueryType" 
        #selectedQueryType="ngModel" 
        (ngModelChange)="queryTypeChange($event)"
        (initialize)="selectedQueryType=queryTypes[0]"
        class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled>QueryType</option>
        <option *ngFor="let qtype of queryTypes" 
                [ngValue]="qtype"
                [selected] = "item.qtype==qtype"
                > 
               {{qtype}} 
        </option>
 </select>
```

and typescript side code for above is

```
@Output() initialize: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 public queryTypes = ["in","not_in"];

  public selectedQueryType = {};
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initialize.emit();
  }
```

I want to run code (initialize)="selectedQueryType=queryTypes[0]" when the component mounts, so that default value of select dropdown get selected, but it is not working.Please help here.

Comment: Why do you want to do that from the template??

Comment: I want to do that on template because, lets say I have this array [{"id":1,"qType":"in"},{"id":2, "qType":"not_in"} ] , then using *ngFor in template I can iterate the array and for each object I have different select dropdown and also I have to initialise the queryTypes dropdown according to "qType".

Comment: TDLR; I still don't know why you want to do this from template insteed of component's code.

Comment: I give a thought on this , and I wonder why I was doing that , I can do this in component's code , thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in component code

```
@Output() initialize: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 public queryTypes = ["in","not_in"];

  public selectedQueryType = {};
  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedQueryType=this.queryTypes[0];
    this.initialize.emit();
  }
```

Why `queryTypes` are a strings and `selectedQueryType` is empty object (not empty string eg) is a mistery to me.